# Disable 2 buttons when one is clicked using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angularJS and am working on a form which has 2 buttons on it (submit & close).

The 'Submit' button has a `type="submit"` and the 'Close' button has a `type="button"`.

I have managed to disable the 'Submit' button when clicked but I also need the 'Close' button to be disabled.

This is the bit I am stuck on.

Also to point out the 'Submit' button on my form is 'Disabled' when the form opens until all the mandatory fields are populated.

All of this currently is done in the HTML.

HTML

```
    <button ng-disabled="enterreminder.remtype.$invalid
                        || enterreminder.remother.$invalid
                        || enterreminder.remarea.$invalid
                        || enterreminder.remdate.$invalid
                        || enterreminder.remsubject.$invalid
                        || enterreminder.remnotes.$invalid"
            type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit()" onclick="this.disabled=true;" title="Click to set the reminder.">
        Submit
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()" title="Click cancel the reminder.">Close</button>
```

So to sum up I want the 'Submit' and 'Close' buttons to be disabled when the 'Submit' button is clicked.  I'm not bothered if the 'Close' button is clicked as the 'Submit' button is already disabled.

Will I need to add code to my controller? and if so can you please help me out with it as I cant seem to find a starting point from Google.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, you need to have a ViewModel property that drives the desired behavior and assign it to each button's `ng-disabled` directive:

```
<button type="submit" ng-disabled="commandButtonsDisabled"
        ng-click="submit(); commandButtonsDisabled = true">Submit</button>

<button type="button" ng-disabled="commandButtonsDisabled"
        ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
```

This just illustrates the point, but it's not a good design to have multiple actions assigned to `ng-click`. The code above also doesn't show how `$scope.commandButtonsDisabled` is initialized (although, being `undefined` it would result in falsy value) and reverted back, so it's better to put this functionality in a controller:

```
.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $http){
   $scope.commandButtonsDisabled = false;
   $scope.submit = function(){
      $scope.commandButtonsDisabled = true;
      $http.post(....)
         .success(...)
         .finally(function(){
             $scope.commandButtonsDisabled = false;
         }
   }
}

<button type="submit" ng-disabled="commandButtonsDisabled" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>   
<button type="button" ng-disabled="commandButtonsDisabled" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
```

**Off-topic:**

It seems that you have a bunch of form elements that you are also testing for validity. Instead of testing each element individually, use the validity of the form:

```
<div ng-form="enterreminder">
   <input ng-model="remtype" ...>
   <input ng-model="remother" ...>
   ...
   <button type="submit" ng-disabled="enterreminder.$invalid || commandButtonsDisabled"...>Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a treat and thanks for the off topic, cleared a few lines from my code.  Don't know why I didn't think of this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example...
**Put this code in .js file**

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

 app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.disable_buttons = false;
    $scope.submit = function () {
        $scope.disable_buttons = true;
    }

 });
```

**And in HTML**

```
  <button ng-disabled="disable_buttons"
                type="submit" ng-click="submit()" title="Click to set the reminder.">
            Submit
        </button>
        <button ng-disabled="disable_buttons" type="button" ng-click="cancel()" title="Click cancel the reminder.">Close</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't your submit and close buttons watch a single scope variable such as 'submit' below:

```
<button ng-disabled="submit" ng-click="submit=true">Submit</button>
<button ng-disabled="submit">close</button>
```